# Petición PUT con Axios genera petición OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Estoy haciendo una petición PUT con Axios, pero en lugar de una petición PUT Axios realiza una petición OPTIONS. Sin embargo al hacer una petición POST sí la realiza bien.  Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?.  Gracias.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.put(`areas/${id}`)
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err.response.data.error)
      })
  })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una duda tal vez un tanto al margen: ¿por qué creas una promesa para manejar los estados de la petición por axios?, cuando ya de por si axios esta basada en promesas

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un tema de CORS

Comment: Porque esa promesa es devuelta a otra función que lo requiere como parte de la lógica del proceso.

Comment: Sí, eso he leído, parece ser un tema de CORS, pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

Comment: Si es tema de CORS, prueba a instalar un plugin en el navegador que te ayude con ese tema temporalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no estaba en el Frontend; estaba en el Backend.  Resulta que los navegadores tienen ciertas restricciones al hacer peticiones hacia un dominio o puerto diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mi caso, estoy haciendo una petición PUT, por lo que el navegador pide autorización.  Para eso primero hace una petición OPTIONS que contiene los datos de la petición que se está haciendo. El servidor debe recibir esa petición y generar una respuesta aceptándola, y luego de eso el navegador enviara la petición PUT, o la que corresponda de acuerdo al caso.

La manera en que el servidor debe responder aceptando la petición es configurando en el HEAD algunos parámetros parámetros.  Por ejemplo:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER   Si el cliente envió esta cabecera personalizada, entonces le decimos que la aceptamos.
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```